# From Json url image to drawable image with AsyncHttpClient Lib

Tags: android, json

my problem is, i have data in JSON, i get that using a AsyncHttpClient Lib, and i populate a ListView...But the problem is, how i can set a Image from Url, this Url is in Json data.

the code:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("q", "London");
    params.put("format","json");
    params.put("num_of_days","5");
    params.put("key", "****");


    client.get("http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx", params,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
            //showProgress(false);

         try {


                JSONArray forecast = response.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("weather");

                for(int i=0;i < forecast.length();i++){                     

                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    JSONObject e = forecast.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray urlJsonArray = e.getJSONArray("weatherIconUrl");
                    JSONObject e1 = urlJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);



                    map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("date", "Data: " +  e.getString("date"));


                    map.put("image",e1.getString("value"));
                    map.put("tempMinC", "Min:" + e.getString("tempMinC"));
                    map.put("tempMaxC", "Max:" + e.getString("tempMaxC"));



                    oslist.add(map);
            }


                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list); 

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Consulting_Test.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { "date" ,"image","tempMinC", "tempMaxC" }, new int[] {
                                R.id.nome,R.id.weatherImage,R.id.esito, R.id.crediti});



                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(Consulting_Test.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        }
```

In this snipped,  i put only the url but i want a Image..sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem with a LazyAdapter.